# unable to boot into centos 6.7 after suspending the system

Tags: linux, boot, backup, centos, bootloader

I suspended the cent os workstation when I restart it is unable to load the OS and I am always displayed with boot option menu like

upgrade or install memory test etc

result of pvscan : 
could not find device with uuid  xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx 
PV /dev/sdb1  vg-scnode1 lvm2 [xx]
PV unknown device   vg-scnode1 lvm2 [xx]

result of lvscan:
ACTIVE /dev/vg-scnode1/lv_root [xx] inherit
IN ACTIVE /dev/vg-scnode1/lv_home [xx] inherit
ACTIVE /dev/vg-scnode1/lv_swap [xx] inherit

kindly help to recover the workstation I have no idea why it is showing boot option menu without any bootable device attached .

please help to recover .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your system messed up and lost devices in fstab.
Try to enter in rescue mode and edit /etc/fstab with vi.
You can use your centos 6 iso for that or read [this](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/rescue-your-system-with-single-user-mode-in-centos-6-rhel-6.html) how to do it on that version.

On Centos 7 is a little different but the aim is the same:

- you hit <kbd>e</kbd> when you see the grub menu
- go to the line starting with the word "linux16", hit "end" to go the end and type: systemd.unit=rescue.target
- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Then it will ask you for the root password.
- Finally type: `vi /etc/fstab`
  and edit carefully your devices. (I suppose you know how to edit fstab!)

Comment: rescue mode might need / (root filesystem) to be remounted read-write (`mount -o rw,remount / `), as well as /usr be mounted (`mount /dev/... /usr` )in order to use vi.